# Place tipsy in place where every div occure

Tags: css, tipsy

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { $('.cat_name').tipsy({gravity: 's'}); });
</script>
```

**TPL Smarty:**

```
<div id="content_inside">
    <a href="#" title="Test" id="1" class="cat_name">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#" title="Test2" id="2" class="cat_name">
        <div class="box">
        </div>
    </a>
</div><!-- content end -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#content_inside {
    height: 500px;
    width: 950px;
    padding:5px;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 261px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.box {
    margin: auto;
    background: url(../images/box1.jpg) no-repeat top left;
}
```

I need to place tipsy in upper center of every div link, how to do that?, for now tipsy are shown always at left side. Example of how is, and how need to be in img: http://oi43.tinypic.com/adka3t.jpg

Comment: http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/

Answer (score 0):

There is an `offset` options in tipsy, which offsets from the elements.

```
$('.cat_name').tipsy({gravity: 's', offset: 20 });
```

Comment: You did not quite understand what was the question :), offset is one thing, making tipsy appear right on top of my divs is that i can't seems to workout.

Comment: @Cameleon, SO you need to show it on left on left box, and center on the middle box. am i right?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, your float: left is causing tipsy to calculate the offset incorrectly. Are you able to lay out your page any differently? As an example, the following boring old tables layout seems to replicate what you're looking for designwise, as well as having the tooltips show up where you want them.

HTML:

```
<div id="content_inside">
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="box"><a href="#" title="Test" id="1" class="cat_name">lkjoijkj lj lkj oij oi</a></td>
    <td class="box"><a href="#" title="Test 2" id="2" class="cat_name">lkjoijkj lj lkj oij oi</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#content_inside {
    height: 500px;
    width: 950px;
    padding:5px;
}

.box {
    width: 300px;
    height: 261px;
    padding: 5px;
}
a { 
    display:block; 
    height: 100%;
}
```